# iTextG causing application crash(Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, itext, itextg

My objective is to superimpose contents of a pdf onto another PDF.

this is the code that I have used:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    String str = null;
    int n = 0;
    try
    {                       
        istr =(InputStream) assetManager.open("Chemistry.pdf");

        reader=new PdfReader(istr);     




        Document document = new Document();
      PdfWriter writer=  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/newhelloPrayToGod.pdf"));


        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.newPage();
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage page;

        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 23);
        canvas.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);



        document.close();

        Log.d("OK", "done");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have used itextG 5.4.3. 
I have even added a copy of the .jar in my libs folder. 
The code compiles, but on running, it just crashes. 
This is the error log:

> 03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.teest/com.example.teest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at com.example.teest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   03-28 16:27:36.693: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

P.S. 
**I have not used any license file(.xml) or anything of that sort. 
the above code is JUST what I have used.**

I tried using the iText jar (not iTextG) too. 
In that, the code worked, but if I used this line in the code

```
canvas.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It would not compile with this error

> The type java.awt.geom.AffineTransform cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

What do I do to get the canvas,addtemplate() running on android? 
I want to superimpose pdfs on another.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how you manage to include the itextG library because i'm getting an error, i've documented it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098721/including-itextg-in-an-android-project-using-android-studio, can you please try to have a look and help if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the exception occurs here:

```
istr =(InputStream) assetManager.open("Chemistry.pdf");
```

The exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream
```

indicates that the `InputStream` in that code line is not the expected `java.io` variant.

Most likely you have an import like

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64.InputStream
```

while you actually wanted

```
import java.io.InputStream
```

Comment: YES!
that was the exact problem.Couldnt have thought of this at all. 
Thanks a lot!