# Unexpected top level exception

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my gradle file, I currently have the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')
}
```

With the above, everything is running correctly. When I'm adding the line `compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.4.0'`, I'm getting the following error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/itextpdf/awt/geom/AffineTransform;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Just remove below from dependencies and try. : `compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')` . That should fix your problem

Comment: what you mean remove below ?

Comment: Sorry i was not clear...just remove `compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')` and it should fix your problem. There is duplicate dependency.

Comment: but i need this library in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception means that there are more than one dependencies/libraries that define the `com/itextpdf/awt/geom/AffineTransform` class.

Make sure you do not have duplicate dependencies.

Comment: if the error happens when i add the dependency com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker, then it must come from this dependency, i looked into it but yet didn't find any such duplicates, this is what is puzzling me

Comment: Check for the `AffineTransform` class. Check the dependencies to see which ones define this class.

Comment: this class is defines only in libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar

Comment: The `iText` has an Android port and a java version. Are you sure you are using the Android varsion?

Comment: yes, in fact the itextG is specifically for the android